# Get environment variable from previous build

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, build, environment-variables

I'm using the [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) Jenkins plugin to set an environment variable during a build step in our deployment pipeline. The next project (according to the order) is a manual step to deploy.I need to access an environment variable set in the build step.

According to the console output I'm doing that properly:

```
[EnvInject] - Executing scripts and injecting environment variables after the SCM step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
FOR=%%i IN ("%NewFile%") DO ( SET FileName=%%~ni )
FILE_NAME=%FileName%

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
```

However in my next step, where I need to access the `$FILE_NAME` variable in order to specify the correct folder to `scp` from I get the following output:

```
[SCP] No file(s) found: releases\$FILE_NAME\*
```

Is there a setting I'm missing or am I attempting to access the variable incorrectly?

I see this option below - "Inject Environment variable" - however this is the same step I used previously to create the `$FILE_NAME` variable. If this is the correct step... how do I use it to get the variable? :)

**EDIT**

By clicking the options below...

[image]

...I'm able to get the following console output when the project builds.

```
 [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
 [EnvInject] - Preparing an environment for the build.
 [EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins system variables.
 [EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins build variables.
 [EnvInject] - Injecting contributions.
 [EnvInject] - Unset unresolved 'USERNAME' variable.
```

However I'm still unable to access `$FILE_NAME`. Below is the option I've selected to set the variable in the previous build step.

[image]

And here is the script that goes in the "Properties Content":

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "C:\Jenkins\workspace\Project\releases\*.nupkg" /B /O:D') DO SET NewFile=%%I
FOR %%i IN ("%NewFile%") DO ( SET FileName=%%~ni )
FILE_NAME = %FileName%
```

Comment: The error message indicates it is taking your filename as folder. Did you recheck the configuration and also the documentation of the fields? (the "?" next to them at the side)

Comment: It's supposed to be used as the folder name (it's used as a file name elsewhere in the previous step). I'll look into the "?" documentation.

Comment: Also, if I use other environmental variables the value comes up in the console output. It seems like it doesn't recognize `$FILE_NAME` as an environmental variable.

Comment: True, seems like that. However, can we be sure there actually is something put into $FILE_NAME in batch script? If not, do you maybe need to `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and use `!Varname!` syntax? Only some blind guess on issues with batch variable expansion, I'll try to reconstruct your issue later tonight.

Comment: Wait, did you put the batch script into the properties field? I think that cannot work as it requires the `java properties file format`syntax. Maybe in the Script Content section it will work?

Comment: I did, had a fundamental misunderstanding of how this plugin was working.

Comment: Ah great, gald its solved.

Answer (score 2):

In a previous build step I look for the most recent file name. In that step I simply output the current version of the file I'm working with like so:

```
@echo FILE_NAME=%FileName%>CurrentVersion.txt
```

Then I add an "Inject Environment Variables" build step and point to the output file. This adds the environment variable as I was hoping for.

[image]